# Enable Keypad For EditText after Calling .requestFocus(); in Android

Tags: android-edittext

I'm Using this Code For Programmatically enable the focus of EDITTEXT,But KeyPad is Not Visible.How to resolve this?

```
edittextmanagedby.requestFocus();
edittextmanagedby.performClick();
edittextmanagedby.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```